# Download HTML table in PDF

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, export-to-pdf, html-pdf

I have spent the last 3 days trying to solve this problem but keep getting the same result...

I have an HTML table which is completed using JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<div id="tb_container">
    <table id="tb_Logbook" class="table table-striped" onload="LoadPilotLogBook()">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><center>DATE</center></th>
              <th colspan="2">DEPARTURE</th>
              <th colspan="2">ARRIVAL</th>
              <th colspan="2">AIRCRAFT</th>
              <th colspan="2">SINGLE PILOT FLIGHT TIME</th>
              <th>MULTI-PILOT</th>
              <th>TOTAL TIME</th>
              <th>NAME OF</th>
              <th colspan="2">LANDINGS</th>
              <th>APPROACH</th>
              <th colspan="2">OPERATIONAL CONDITION TIME</th>
              <th colspan="4">PILOT FUNCTION TIME</th>
              <th colspan="3">FLIGHT SIM TRAINING</th>
              <th>REMARKS AND</th>
              <th colspan="2">ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th><center>dd/mm/yyyy</center></th>
              <th>Place</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Place</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Model</th>
              <th>Registration</th>
              <th>SE</th>
              <th>ME</th>
              <th>FLIGHT TIME</th>
              <th>OF FLIGHT</th>
              <th>Pilot in command</th>
              <th>Day</th>
              <th>Night</th>
              <th>IFR</th>
              <th>Night</th>
              <th>IFR</th>
              <th>PIC</th>
              <th>Co-Pilot</th>
              <th>Dual</th>
              <th>Instructor</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>ENDORSMENTS</th>
              <th>EDIT</th>
              <th>SUPPR</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            //AutoGenerated via JS 
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**I have included all these files:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/someatoms/jsPDF-AutoTable/master/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.0.10/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    window.html2canvas = html2canvas
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [297, 210]);
title = "Your Logbook",
source = $('#tb_container')[0];

specialElementHandlers = {

    '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {

        return true
    }
};



margins = {
    top: 100,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 10,
    right: 10
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {

doc.addHTML($('#tb_Logbook')[0], function () {
    title,
    source,
    margins.left, 
    margins.top, { 
        'width': margins.width, 
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },
 doc.save('LOGBOOK_' + userLastName + '_' + userFirstName + '.pdf');
 });


});
```

When I click the button to export as PDF I get this file:

[image: My PDF exported]

I really don't now how to deal with this problem.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You can also use jsPDF [html PlugIn](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/modules_html.js.html), a [replacement of `addHtml()`](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML). I can't find the CDN for [`html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.12`](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases) so I am not able to make a code snippet here. The following code worked for me. And the pdf content is searchable and clearer. You might need to adjust the size of the page though.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script><!-- html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.11 or higher version is needed -->
<script>
    function download() {
        let pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [1920, 640]);
        pdf.html(document.getElementById('tb_Logbook'), {
            callback: function (pdf) {
                pdf.save('test.pdf');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This could load my PDF and I get a total white page with this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'`

Comment: @flyer74 are you using `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>`? I tried using this version and got the exact same error you have. You'll need to download the newer version from the [link](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases) I gave you.

Comment: That's true ! By dl the file I havn't got no longer error to generate the PDF, but now I've got a PDF with 35 white pages .... The only one error write on the console is : `Invalid value given for Length: "auto"`

Comment: @flyer74 check [this](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1514#issuecomment-458566071) out. but its' time to google yourself though!

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the `background-color:white`. I think the problem is html2canvas is giving you a png image that is transparent and JsPDF will convert it to jpg. So all the transparent pixels converted to black.

In short, Try to set the body, html, table `background-color` to `white`.

```js
window.html2canvas = html2canvas
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [297, 210]);
title = "Your Logbook",
source = $('#tb_container')[0];

specialElementHandlers = {

    '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {

        return true
    }
};



margins = {
    top: 100,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 10,
    right: 10
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {

  doc.addHTML($('#tb_Logbook')[0], function () {
      title,
      source,
      margins.left, 
      margins.top, { 
          'width': margins.width, 
          'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      },
   doc.save('LOGBOOK_.pdf');
   });
 
 });
```

```css
*, html, body, table{
  background-color:white;
  width:100%;
}

#cmd{
  border:1px solid blue;
  color:white;
  background-color:lightblue;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  width:200px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/someatoms/jsPDF-AutoTable/master/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.0.10/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<div class="cmd" id="cmd">Click to Export</div>
<div id="tb_container">
    <table id="tb_Logbook" class="table table-striped" onload="LoadPilotLogBook()">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><center>DATE</center></th>
              <th colspan="2">DEPARTURE</th>
              <th colspan="2">ARRIVAL</th>
              <th colspan="2">AIRCRAFT</th>
              <th colspan="2">SINGLE PILOT FLIGHT TIME</th>
              <th>MULTI-PILOT</th>
              <th>TOTAL TIME</th>
              <th>NAME OF</th>
              <th colspan="2">LANDINGS</th>
              <th>APPROACH</th>
              <th colspan="2">OPERATIONAL CONDITION TIME</th>
              <th colspan="4">PILOT FUNCTION TIME</th>
              <th colspan="3">FLIGHT SIM TRAINING</th>
              <th>REMARKS AND</th>
              <th colspan="2">ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th><center>dd/mm/yyyy</center></th>
              <th>Place</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Place</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Model</th>
              <th>Registration</th>
              <th>SE</th>
              <th>ME</th>
              <th>FLIGHT TIME</th>
              <th>OF FLIGHT</th>
              <th>Pilot in command</th>
              <th>Day</th>
              <th>Night</th>
              <th>IFR</th>
              <th>Night</th>
              <th>IFR</th>
              <th>PIC</th>
              <th>Co-Pilot</th>
              <th>Dual</th>
              <th>Instructor</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>ENDORSMENTS</th>
              <th>EDIT</th>
              <th>SUPPR</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            //AutoGenerated via JS 
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

You can also test your this answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/fvuan6hs/)